# Firebase once call not returning

Tags: firebase

I have a call to once where I get a value. It works fine when I'm testing on localhost, but once I deploy statically to GitHub Pages, my call to once never returns. Here's my code:

```
async get(path) {
    const ref = new Firebase(`https://resplendent-fire-9351.firebaseio.com/${path}`);
    const dataSnapshot = await ref.once('value');
    console.log(dataSnapshot);
    return dataSnapshot.val();
}
```

When deployed, dataSnapshot is never logged. On localhost though, everything works just fine. I'm wondering if there is some kind of domain origin issue. I'm loading firebase from the CDN, and I'm logging the path that I pass in as well, and it doesn't seem to have any problems.

Comment: Upon further inspection, it looks like the ref is what is actually never returning, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
async get(path) {
    const ref = new Firebase(`https://resplendent-fire-9351.firebaseio.com/${path}`);
    return await ref.once('value');
}
```